# $subject in php mail form returning only first word in string

Tags: php, email

I am currently learning php for a web interface class, and one of our assignments is to generate a basic form to send an email with.  We then have to be able to send a sample of that form in an email through html. I want to do this showing the the input that was entered when the email was sent.  I've got most of it working, I just can't get the $subject variable to completely populate within the sample. It will only show one word, and skip all others after the first space character.  (The same is true of the $from variable, however this will typically be an email address and thus its not a major issue)

For example, if I send an email with the subject,"This is a test", when I receive the email in my inbox I will see the full subject "This is a test" in my email's subject line.  But when I open the email itself and look at the generated form sample I will only see "This" as the filled in subject.

I am using the input, type="text" tag to enter the subject and I imagine that is part of the reason.  I can solve the problem using a textarea tag, but that's not really conventional and seems to defeat the purpose of the exercise.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:
(The first block is just a function to generate the form.)

```
function createForm() //create form upon page load
{
    echo '<form method="post">' . '<br />';
    echo '<fieldset>' . '<br />';
    echo '<legend><p>Heading</p></legend>' . '<br />';
    echo 'To: <input name="to" type="text" />' . '<br />';
    echo 'From: <input name="from" type="text" />' . '<br />';
    echo 'Subject: <input name="subject" type="text"  />' . '<br />';
    echo '</fieldset>' . '<br />';
    echo '<fieldset>' . '<br />';
    echo '<legend><p>Content</p></legend>' . '<br />';
    echo 'Message: <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>' . '<br />';
    echo '<input name="send" type="submit" />' . '<br />';
    echo '</fieldset>' . '<br />';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

And the actual send email code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['to'])) //send email 
{
    $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To:  $from"  . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: $subject" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "\r\n";

    //html message
    $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Headings</legend>
    To: <input type="text" name="to" value=' . $_REQUEST['to'] . ' /><br />
    From: <input type="text" name="from" value=' . $_REQUEST['from'] . ' /><br />
    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value=' . $_REQUEST['subject'] . ' />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Content</legend>
    Message: <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10">' . $_REQUEST['message'] . '</textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="send" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>';   

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$from,$headers);

    echo "Message sent, thank you. <br />";
    echo '<a href="email.php">Return</a>';
}
else
{
    createForm(); //create form if no $to set. 
}
```

Comment: why are you sending another form in your email ? I think your code could be lot simpler.

Comment: and you should change `/r/n` to `\r\n`

Comment: It's what our professor assigned. Outside of sending a client a sample, I know this generally won't be used much.  But none the less, its the assignment.

Comment: thanks with the \r\n, didn't see that. nice catch.  Don't think it'll solve my issue, but helpful regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML interpreter in the mail program is looking at the input elements and seeing the `value` attribute followed by a single unquoted word. Then it sees a bunch of other attributes without values. Quote the value properly in the first place. And *sanitize* too; you don't want your clients being hacked because of an email that was sent from your system.

Comment: "Quote the value properly in the first place"

I guess this is what I'm trying to figure out.  If I just quote the variable, it just gets treated as a string and displays the literal variable.  If I echo the variable I just get the php code in the fields.  The REPLACE with the concatenation seemed to be the only way I could get it to work. 

Admittedly, I'm a novice with php.  So I'm sure I'm just overlooking/botching syntax here.  (Sanitizing was the next step, but wanted to get this working first).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `... value="' . sanitize($_REQUEST['...']) . '" />`